# WordPress Custom Query

Tags: query-posts, mysql

I have posts that use a custom field for start date and end date.
`query_posts` returns an array of posts that exist in the category I'm filtering.
How do I query posts using this custom field that has date i.e. 03/11/2010 and not the full array. Pagination works on the full array so it returns all posts. I can use an if else to only show the posts newer that today, then pagination doesn't work.
Would I have to build a custom mysql query?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

 $querystr = "
    SELECT wposts.* 
    FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
    WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'date_field' 
    AND wpostmeta.meta_value = '03/11/2010' 
    AND wposts.post_status = 'publish' 
    AND wposts.post_type = 'post' 
    ORDER BY wposts.post_date DESC
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr, OBJECT);

 ?>
```

**Then you would access $pageposts as an object**

Comment: this I believe is my answer! interested in doing some WPMU development?

Comment: I would appreciate you checking this off as an answer!

Comment: I hunted for that large 'tick'... thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom query using following filters `query_vars`, `posts_join`, `posts_where`, `posts_groupby`.
here's the codex link to [custom queries](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Queries).
Some examples are listed there for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) using [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

```
$my_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'date_field',
            'value => '03/11/2010',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
) );
```

By default it will search for published posts.

I would also suggest to store date in yyyy/mm/dd format. Sorting by this field will be much easier if you do this so.